# How can I overcome "Error: Cycle" on digitalocean droplet

Tags: terraform

I am sure this is a simple problem that I don't know how to interpret it at the moment.

I use 3 droplets(called rs) and have a template file which configures each.

```
[..]

data "template_file" "rsdata" {
  template = file("files/rsdata.tmpl")
  count    = var.count_rs_nodes
  vars = {
    docker_version   = var.docker_version
    private_ip_rs    = digitalocean_droplet.rs[count.index].ipv4_address_private
    private_ip_mysql = digitalocean_droplet.mysql.ipv4_address_private
  }
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "rs" {
  count              = var.count_rs_nodes
  image              = var.image
  name               = "${var.prefix}-rs-${count.index}"
  region             = var.region
  size               = var.rs_size
  private_networking = true
  user_data          = data.template_file.rsdata.rendered
  ssh_keys           = var.ssh_keys
  depends_on         = ["digitalocean_droplet.mysql"]
}

[..]
```

When I do a terraform apply I get:
`Error: Cycle: digitalocean_droplet.rs, data.template_file.rsdata`

Note this is terraform 0.12

What am I doing wrong and how can I overcome this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is returned because the `data.template_file.rsdata` resource refers to the `digitalocean_droplet.rs` resource and vice-versa. That creates an impossible situation for Terraform: there is no ordering Terraform could use to process these that would ensure that all of the necessary data is available at each step.

The key problem is that the private IPv4 address for a droplet is allocated as part of creating it, but the `user_data` is used as part of that creation and so it cannot include the IPv4 address that is yet to be allocated.

The most straightforward way to deal with this would be to *not* include the droplet's IP address as part of its `user_data` and instead arrange for whatever software is processing that `user_data` to fetch the IP address of the host directly from the network interface at runtime. The kernel running in that droplet will know what the IP address is, so you can retrieve it from there in principle.

---

If for some reason including the IP addresses in the `user_data` is unavoidable (this can occur, for example, if there are a set of virtual machines that all need to be aware of *each other*) then a more complex alternative is to separate the allocation of the IP addresses from the creation of the instances. DigitalOcean doesn't have a mechanism to create *private* network interfaces separately from the droplets they belong to, so in this case it would be necessary to use public IP addresses via `digitalocean_floating_ip`, which may not be appropriate for all situations:

```
resource "digitalocean_floating_ip" "rs" {
  count = var.count_rs_nodes

  region = var.region
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "rs" {
  count = var.count_rs_nodes

  image              = var.image
  name               = "${var.prefix}-rs-${count.index}"
  region             = var.region
  size               = var.rs_size
  private_networking = true
  ssh_keys           = var.ssh_keys
  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/files/rsdata.tmpl", {
    docker_version   = var.docker_version
    private_ip_rs    = digitalocean_floating_ip.rs[count.index].ip_address
    private_ip_mysql = digitalocean_droplet.mysql.ipv4_address_private
  })
}

resource "digitalocean_floating_ip_assignment" "rs" {
  count = var.count_rs_nodes

  ip_address = digitalocean_floating_ip.rs[count.index].ip_address
  droplet_id = digitalocean_droplet.rs[count.index].id
}
```

Because the "floating IP assignment" is created as a separate step after the droplet is launched, there will be some delay before the floating IP is associated with the instance and so whatever software is relying on that IP address must be resilient to running before the association is created.

Note that I also switched from using `data "template_file"` to [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) because the data source is offered only for backward-compatibility with Terraform 0.11 configurations; the built-in function is the recommended way to render external template files in Terraform 0.12, and avoids the need for a separate configuration block.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin for explaining this. Makes sense now